# how to solve problem with deleting listview item

Tags: flutter, dart

i need to remove listview items on button click

local_data_source

```
Future<void> deleteTask(int index) async {
    final box = await asyncBox;
    await box.deleteAt(index);
  }
```

tasks_repository

```
Future<void> deleteLocalTask(int index) async {
    await tasksLocalDataSource.deleteTask(index);
  }
```

tasks_provider

```
Future<void> deleteTasks(int index) async {
    await tasksRepository.deleteLocalTask(index);
  }
```

button that removes element

```
 return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
               final delete = context
                       .read(tasksProvider.notifier)
                       .deleteTasks(tasks.length);
                       delete;
                      log('$delete');
                              },
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: on tap task didnt delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post enough code to actually see if this is the *only* mistake.

But in the code you posted, you are passing `tasks.length` as the index of the task to delete. While I don't know which task you *want* to delete, `tasks.length` is definetely *not* the index of one of your tasks, it's practically guaranteed to not be an index of your tasks at all.

Your methods all seem to deal with the `async`/ `await` pattern just fine and then in your `onTap` method it reads as if you never heard of `Future<>` before. If those methods were written by different persons, maybe contact the first one and ask for advice. If all of it was written by you, you need a break and a coffee or something.